# Proguard fails with Google Play Services library

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-services

I'm unable to build my package with `Proguard` enabled after updating `Google Play Services` library. My project `minSdkVersion` is **9**. I am using following version of services lib:

```
android:versionCode="4323030"
android:versionName="4.3.23 (1069729-030)" >
```

The library states `minSdk` also **9**.

And getting error:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
Class       = [com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil]
Method      = [showErrorDialogFragment(ILandroid/app/Activity;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z]
Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [com/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment] (not even immediate super class [android/app/DialogFragment]))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find any super classes of [com/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment] (not even immediate super class [android/app/DialogFragment])
```

Following related to gms is found in my proguard file:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

`DialogFragment` was added in API level 11. Is this a failure with the services library or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build against API level 11 that contains the missing class. The library itself probably has a fallback mode for older APIs, but ProGuard still needs to process the entire application, including the newer code.

Comment: For a quick solution, I took older maps library to use, but most likely this works, I just need to handle all coming deprecations and API changes properly.